# JSONException: End of input character 0 of

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I was following [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) to implement login/registration to my app.

I've done everything exactly as the tutorial says, except that I put the code inside AsyncTask, since network calls can't be maed insied main thread.

Here is my code:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
Button btnRegister;
Button btnLinkToLogin;
EditText inputFullName;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView registerErrorMsg;

// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);

    // Register Button Click event
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new register().execute();
        }
    });

    // Link to Login Screen
    btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // Close Registration View
            finish();
        }
    });
}

class register extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
        String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);

        // check for login response
        try {
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                    // user successfully registred
                    // Store user details in SQLite Database
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                    // Clear all previous data in database
                    userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                    // Launch Dashboard Screen
                    Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                    dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(dashboard);
                    // Close Registration Screen
                    finish();
                }else{
                    // Error in registration
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

This is the error I get:

```
10-02 18:26:55.920    1367-1386/? E/Buffer Error﹕ Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
10-02 18:26:55.920    1367-1386/? E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
10-02 18:26:55.924    1367-1386/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.matejhacin.highfive.RegisterActivity$register.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:78)
        at com.matejhacin.highfive.RegisterActivity$register.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:67)
```

I get the same error at login and register screen. I have my USB Web Server with SQL databse up and running.

registerUser(...) method:

```
public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}
```

Comment: You got parse exception: most likely because the result of the API call is NULL. Please check userFunction.registerUser(...) implementation, before converting the API result to JSON

Comment: I've checked it but I can't see what could be wrong with it. I've edited my original post for you if you could help me with that.

Comment: Please check the source code of JSONParser.java it seems that getJSONFromUrl method is failing and returning null JSON object, they already printing the stack trace, you should see the problem in your log cat.